# Javascript promise not delaying function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, revealing-module-pattern

I'm using ES6 javascript promises in Chrome and am having trouble understanding why the promise executed within the **function _getStatus()** is not returning the  **result** argument in the success handler which would result in the alert box containing "done".  Instead, I get an alert box that says "undefined".

```
myNameSpace = function(){    
    var obj = {
        groupA: {
            status: "inactive"
        },
        groupB: {
            status: "active"
        }
    };

    function _getStatus(group){
        _finishTask().then(function(result){
            return result; // doesn't return anything
        });
    }

    function _finishTask(){
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){            
            // do some task before resolving
            resolve("done");
        });
        return promise;
    };

    return{
        getStatus:_getStatus
    }
}();

$(function(){
    alert(myNameSpace.getStatus("groupA")); // why is this "undefined" instead of "done"?
});
```

Comment: Right, `getStatus` doesn't return anything. You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is not how Promises work. You need to make sure both `_getStatus` and `_finishTask` return Promise objects. Then you will be able to use those promises API methods to execute subsequent code what promise is resolved.

So your code should look something like this:

```
myNameSpace = function() {
    var obj = {
        groupA: {
            status: "inactive"
        },
        groupB: {
            status: "active"
        }
    };

    function _getStatus(group) {
        return _finishTask().then(function(result) {
            return result + " and tested";
        });
    }

    function _finishTask() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // do some task before resolving
            resolve("done");
        });
    };

    return {
        getStatus: _getStatus
    }
}();

myNameSpace.getStatus("groupA").then(alert);
```

Finally, regarding this construction:

```
return _finishTask().then(function(result) {
    return result;
});
```

`_finishTask` returns a Promise object, when this promise is resolved you get into `then` callback. Whatever value you return from this callback becomes a new resolution value for the subsequent success callbacks down the resolution chain.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/K1SWKuTYA3e46RxdzkCe?p=preview

Comment: thanks the explanation.  Just in case this helps somebody else, I found a helpful article - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).  Here's a paragraph that improved my understanding how promises work (i.e. how _getStatus also returns a promise object even though only 1 was explicitly created in _finishTask): If you return a value, the next "then" is called with that value. However, if you return something promise-like (anything with a "then" method as promise-like), the next "then" waits on it, and is only called when that promise settles (succeeds/fails).

Answer (score 1):

You cant return a result from an asynchronous function as the code running it has already finished by the time the response is returned.

You can however pass in a callback to execute once the code is complete:

```
function _getStatus(group, callback){
    _finishTask().then(function(result){
        callback(result);
    });
}


$(function(){
    myNameSpace.getStatus("groupA", function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

or use the promise api itself (in this case your _getStatus method is a little redundant):

```
function _getStatus(group){
    return _finishTask();
}


$(function(){
    myNameSpace.getStatus("groupA").then(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @technix!  Your first sentence captures my misunderstanding.  I agree with what you wrote re: _getStatus being redundant in the example, but my code was simplified to make the question clearer.  Because I need to include stuff in _getStatus, I thought @dfsq's solution was slightly more fleshed for me though your solution also helped me as well.  Thanks!